# What is Space Time code? Is there any good book/thesis to understand the subject?

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

I am interested to learn  [Space Time code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_time_code). 
Is there any understandable books/ lecture notes/ thesis for beginners?

Comment: ...and where'd you hear about this business?

Comment: Two pieces of advice: You might want to accept some of the answers to your previous questions; and on an internet forum where people occasionally ask about wacky stuff, when you talk about learning the space-time code, I'd provide enough context for people to tell that that's less wacky than it sounds. :-)

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article with references. Also, _please accept some answers to your previous questions._

Comment: @Qiaochu, other moderators. On second thought my answer comes disturbingly close to advertising books written by close colleagues. I really don't know, whether that is appropriate here. Should I delete this "answer"?

Comment: (meta: @Jyrki: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717) for instance...)

Comment: @QY: I have accepted some answers of my questions. Please see comment. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user12290: And now I see that you have *unaccepted* those answers. Why? Did those answers all of a sudden *stop* being useful? Even if you don't want to accept them, you can vote on answers by clicking the arrows on the upper left of each post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a beginning engineer I shamelessly recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470845422) written by my former colleagues. It does not get into some of the newer aspects of the theory such as DMT-optimality and multiuser theory. If you are an engineering major interested in the applications of algebraic number theory in this area, but don't really know much about it, then *Frederique Oggier, Emanuele Viterbo, Algebraic Number Theory And Code Design For Rayleigh Fading Channels* is a quick read.

==============

Edit/addendum:

For DMT-stuff there is more than enough material available at [David Tse's homepage](https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/wireless_book.html)

Comment: No shame indeed in linking to colleagues' books, but maybe it's better to [link to Amazon...](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470845422)

Comment: @J.M.  However the Amazon link seems to be to the hardcover \$155 edition, while the other comes in below \$30.

Comment: @Ross: Well, it's still contingent that you shop around for better prices even after you see something neat on Amazon... :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will start of your mentioned book.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Fixed a rotten link. Sorry about the bump.

Comment: While you're fixing links, the other one was also broken, but by comparison with archive.org I'm pretty confident I've got the right replacement.